# Python Classes and Collections

Tags: python, list

This is a best practices question

Let say, I have a class object, like so:

```
class ClassOfObjects:
     def __init__(self, name):
       self.name = name
     ...
```

Lets say, I instantiate 3 of these objects

```
a = ClassOfObjects('one')
b = ClassOfObjects('two')
c = ClassOfObjects('three')
```

Now, I want to create a list of my objects. One obvious way is to create list object

```
ListOfObjects = [a,b,c]
```

I find that limiting. Specially when I trying to search find an object with a particular object. Is anyone aware of any best practices.

Comment: use a dictionary to store them if the problem is retrieving them

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can have each instance register itself with the class when it's created:

```
class K(object):
     registry = {}
     def __init__(self, name):
         self.name = name
         self.registry[name] = self
```

Then `K.registry` is a dictionary of all the instances you've created, with the name as the key. You don't even need to assign the instance to a variable, since it's accessible through the registry. You can also iterate over the instances easily.

Perhaps if you share more information about your use cases, someone can provide a better alternative.

Comment: also consider using a `set`; this can be more accurate depending on your requirements and semantics of equality/duplicates

Comment: @kindall Does it matter if at line 5, I do `K.registry[name] = self`? Because I thought you supposed to do it like that? I have a question that is "bugged" because I didn't refer to the class, I referred to the `self`.

Comment: Since you're not *assigning* to the attribute `registry` of the instance, only modifying it, `self` or `K` (or better yet, `type(self)`) are equivalent ways to get to the same dict.